# Reverse percentage formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

Apparently "reverse percentage calculations" are a confusing topic (I looked through existing questions) - but I'm not sure I understand it myself.

I have a counter in my Google Sheets that is counting down a certain number of cells, and then I have the total range of cells.

So for example: my counter is at 6000 and its counting down through a range of 7000 cells.
What I'm trying to do is calculate the percentage that it's done counting down.

When I divide the part by the total, I obviously get something like 90% - which is not what I want. It should be like 2% (or whatever) :P

Does anyone know the formula I should apply here?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not programming related

Comment: I didn't tag programming either. :) However it is GSheets formula related.

Comment: This is highly unclear. You are counting from A down to B, and you want to calculate progress as a percentage, so that f(A) = 0 and F(B) = 100, is that right? If so, the formula is f(x) + (A-x)/(A-B)

Comment: hm what does f represent in that formula? (but yes you're correct in what I meant)

Comment: the best you can do is to provide copy/sample of your sheet with example of exact desired result. someone will jump in and solve it in 5minutes

Comment: Basically all I'm trying to do is have 0 be 100% and 100 be 0%. 
If X=20 - what's the formula that'll tell me the percentage of X if 0=100% and 100=0%

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=1-COUNTA(A:A)/A1
```

[image]

(cell formatted as a percentage)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved it.

If A is counting down from 100 and 0 = 100%, then the information I was originally missing was the difference between 100 and A.

So in my case:

A3:
=ROWS(A1:A)-A2

(A1:A is 100%)
(A2 is the current countdown)

So for example if ROWS(A1:A) = 10 (total rows in your sheet) & if my current countdown is 3 then:

A3:
=ROWS(A1:A)-A2 = 7

Then we calculate the percentage by:

A4:
=A3/ROWS(A1:A)

That should give you the correct percentage.